ddev Chrome/Chrome or Chrome/Chromium
I want to re-configure my current entity print so it works on chrome/php-chrome of chromium instead of the old wkhtmltopdf. But at the moment I have a problem with setting up any of those libraries in a ddev environment. Checking the list of existing addons, as I can see, the closest subject is ddev-selenium-standalone-chrome and headless-chrome, but as I understand, both of these options have nothing to do with my goal.
Know how to properly configure ddev and install extension Chrome of Chromium? Or I get it wrong and incorrectly, and ddev-selenium-standalone-chrome or headless-chrome comply with my request?

I guess you're trying to create PDF files, and want to switch from using wkhtmltopdf? Could you give a link to the technique you want to use?

You might want to open an issue in https://github.com/skeemer/ddev-wkhtmltox/issues talking about this as well.

Greetings @rfay, thx for your quick response.
I need to install a headless Chrome library or executable that the module can call to render HTML as PDF. This typically involves installing Google Chrome or Chromium (a free and open-source version of Chrome).
Drupal has a module https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print_chrome, that works only when Chrome or Chromium is installed on your web server. So I think about how to correctly perform that via ddev.

If you just want chromium installed, use webimage_extra_packages: [chromium] in your .ddev/config.yaml. See if that works with the Drupal module.

I'm using spatie/browsershot for my PDF printing, but I think the setup will point you in the same direction.
config.yaml
webimage_extra_packages: [gconf-service, libasound2, libatk1.0-0, libc6, libcairo2, libcups2, libdbus-1-3, libexpat1, libfontconfig1, libgbm1, libgcc1, libgconf-2-4, libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0, libglib2.0-0, libgtk-3-0, libnspr4, libpango-1.0-0, libpangocairo-1.0-0, libstdc++6, libx11-6, libx11-xcb1, libxcb1, libxcomposite1, libxcursor1, libxdamage1, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6, libxrandr2, libxrender1, libxss1, libxtst6, ca-certificates, fonts-liberation, libappindicator1, libnss3, lsb-release, xdg-utils, wget, libgbm-dev, libxshmfence-dev]

Install the puppeteer npm package and then use puppeteer to install headless chrome.
# ddev ssh
npx puppeteer browsers install chrome

The other thing to note is that in the DDEV environment, you need to run without sandbox mode.
